# NPE while using createBitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I got an NPE this line:

```
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(base64EncodeDecode.decodeBase64(taskItems.get("task_image")));
```

Logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
```

The Problem is that `taskItems.get("task_image")` includes 4 spaces instead of a decoded `base64 String`.
How can I check if the `base64` `String` is a correct `String`.

I tried something like:

```
String taskimage = taskItems.get("task_image");
if (taskimage.trim().length() > 10)
```

But, what if there is 200 of times the 'a' token.

What can I do to check if the `Bitmap` `String` is REALLY a `Bitmap` `String`?

Comment: 1. Post logcat upon NPE please 2. What the hell is `Bitmap String`? `Bitmap` or `String`? Anyway, could check with `x instance of Bitmap`.

Comment: `bm` is null, so calling `getWidth()` on it throws `NullPointerException`. Your problem is that `Bitmap.createBitmap()` returns null.

Comment: so what can I do to check if it's null? I can't really use a if case because it crashes my app in this line.

Comment: No it does not -- `getWidth()` crashed, not the line of code you posted.

Comment: The NPE comes in this line i have posted

Comment: Your NPE comes from a line doing: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference`. Check the return value of `Bitmap.createBitmap`, `base64EncodeDecode.decodeBase64`, `taskItems.get`... you're doing zero checks.

Comment: Okay I have added some checks and now it works thank you

Comment: Okay, posted my recommendations as an answer. Thanks to accept if it was enough help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bm` is null, so calling `getWidth()` on it throws `NullPointerException`. Your problem is that `Bitmap.createBitmap()` returns null.

Your NPE comes from a line doing: "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference".

Check the return value of `Bitmap.createBitmap()`, `base64EncodeDecode.decodeBase64()`, `taskItems.get()` to avoid nulls.

You're doing zero checks.